# How to cast to generic collection

Tags: c#, generics, casting, abstract-class

I have a generic collection Path where T is Segment - Segment is abstract class.
I have a derived class ClosedPath of Path which contains derived classes SpecialLineSegments from abstract base class Segment via intermediate class LineSegment.
I'm trying to select the path which meets a condition and then i'll modify it such that it may contain different types of segment and may not be a ClosedPath anymore....so i'm trying to cast to Path. Compiler gives error that this cast is not possible.

```
       public static void Method1(ClosedPath[] paths)
       {
            bool condition = false;
            //working code..

            Path<Segment> Pslct = new Path<Segment>();
            foreach (ClosedPath P in paths)
            {
                if (condition)
                {
                    //working code

                    Pslct = (Path<Segment>) P;

                }

            }
       }
```

Path is defined as follows...

```
public class Path<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : Segment
{
    private List<T> segments = new List<T>();

    public List<T> Segments 
    {  
        set { segments = value;}
        get { return this.segments; } 
    }

    public T this[int pos]
    {
        get { return (T)segments[pos]; }
        set { segments[pos] = value; }
    }

    public Path()
    {
      this.Segments = new List<T>();   
    }

    public Path(List<T> s)
    {
        this.Segments = s;
    }

    public void AddSegment(T s) {Segments.Add(s);}

    public int Count {get {return Segments.Count;}}

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    { return Segments.GetEnumerator();}
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    { return Segments.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

ClosedPath derived from

```
  public class LinePath<T> : Path<T>, IEnumerable<T> where T : LineSegment
  {
       //working code
  }
```

LineSegment derives from Segment

Comment: Write an explicit conversion operator.

Comment: I thought i could do this but I also thought explicit conversion operators were just for unrelated classes (by inheritance). I would have thought my two Paths Path<Segment> and ClosedPath are related by inheritance.

Comment: What is the base class of ClosedPath?

Comment: A generic class derived from Path<T>....will edit above.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010...so not sure.

Comment: @gwizardry the classes are not related by inheritance.  For example, `List<string>` is not related by inheritance to `List<object>`.  Similarly, `Path<ClosedSegment>` is not related to `Path<Segment>` by inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cast from  `ClosedPath` (`Path<LineSegment>`) to `Path<Segment>` is due to the `List<T>`.
ex:

```
List<Segment> foo = new List<LineSegment>(); //Will not compile
```

If you were to convert directly, you could have a `Path<Segment>` that was internally a `ClosedPath`.  This would cause `AddSegment(Segment s)` to fail as it would attempt to add `Segment s` to the internal `List<LineSegment>`.  Therefore, you must cast the internal List when converting.

```
if (condition)
{
    //working code

    // Convert the ClosedPath LineSegments to Sements to create the Path<Segment>
    Pslct = new Path<Segment>(P.Cast<Segment>().ToList());
```

**<OldAnswer>**

Assuming that `ClosedPath : LinePath<LineSegment>` you should be able to use LINQ `.Cast<>()`.

```
Path<Segment> Pslct = paths.Cast<Path<Segment>>();
```

**</OldAnswer>**

Comment: Yes it does. I have no LINQ experience....maybe i should be reading up on LINQ fast.

Comment: Looked a bit more into this - .Cast will not work.  Edited answer.

Comment: Explicit conversion solution compiles, but have a few other things to do before testing at run time.

Comment: Due to `List<T>` being invariant, this throws a wrench into the works with converting between these classes.  After running a few tests on my end using the code snippets provided `.Cast` doesn't work as expected - you will likely need to do the conversion manually (see above)